# When using google scripts to turn a spreadsheet into an xml document, where does google scripts send the finished product?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

When using google scripts to turn a spreadsheet into an xml document, where does google scripts send the finished product?

I have been searching the [XMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service) documentation page, and I can't find it anywhere.

In the sample code, they show:

> var document = XmlService.createDocument(root);
>
> var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
>
> Logger.log(xml);

Which seems like they just print the entire xml document into the script log?  I tried it, and it really seems like that's what they're doing.

I'm looking for a function that, when called, will create a new document in my google drive called "whatever.xml", but it doesn't appear to exist?

What am I missing?

I saw [ContentService has a text output that will download the file to your computer](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output#downloadAsFile) when it runs the script, but this is a script I need to

1)have run automatically every night

2)be stored online in a shared drive

and I'd rather not have to re-upload the file manually when the script runs just so the final output is accesible to the project collaborators (this is a script that I will have run on a timer at midnight every day.) (Also, will it still download the file if I don't have a browser window open when the script runs?)

Comment: I'm guessing that you will want to build a [webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and use a doGet()  and return the xml document with [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)

Comment: Have you researched `DriveApp`? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  official documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DriveApp class to create a file in your Drive.

For example:

```js
function createAndSaveXml() {
  // Create xml element
  var root = XmlService.createElement('threads');

  // Get some data for example from your Gmail inbox 
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var child = XmlService.createElement('thread')
    .setAttribute('messageCount', threads[i].getMessageCount())
    .setAttribute('isUnread', threads[i].isUnread())
    .setText(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject());
    root.addContent(child);
  }

  // Create xml document
  var document = XmlService.createDocument(root);

  // Pretty print the xml document
  var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);

  // Save it to Drive at the root folder
  DriveApp.createFile('document.xml', xml);
}
```

You will see a file named "document.xml" in your Drive with the xml content.

---

**Recommended reading:**

- [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)